# Check out code from svn without creating folder

Tags: svn

I have code on svn, like the following hierarchy:

```
myFolder    
|--myFolder1    
|--myFolder2
|--myFolder3
```

When I check out code using command `svn co http://my.repository.path/myFoder`, It creates **myFolder** and checks out data inside the folder but I need to check out data of **myFolder** without creating **myFolder**.

Comment: Assuming you want the contents of `myFolder` into the current folder, did you try `svn co http://my.repository.path/myFoder .`? [svn checkout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html)

Comment: Your assumption is correct @crashmstr. I am trying to run this command.

Comment: Thank you @crashmstr. This worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the full version of the svn command here

```
> svn co --help
checkout (co): Check out a working copy from a repository.
usage: checkout URL[@REV]... [PATH]
```

So when you use instead `svn co http://my.repository.path/myFolder .` (see the point at the  end for the current directory), it should checkout the content of the directory directly into the folder itself.